# CSS - padding with percent vs. padding with pixels

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a UI that's all relatively based on the current DOM size. I'm doing this by heavily using percents.

One thing I'm trying to do is render nodes inside of an absolute container with padding-top:%.

The size that the % calculates is totally out of whack for me. I'm not sure what number the % is based off of but it certainly isn't the parent node. However, padding with a fixed pixel in the same dom hierarchy works fine.

See the JS fiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/AK3eT/

```
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:600px;border:solid 1px black;position:absolute; top:10%; width:30%; height:40%;">
    <div style="border:solid 1px blue;height:20px;margin-top:20%"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;width:600px;border:solid 1px black;position:absolute; left:160px;top:10%; width:30%; height:40%;">
    <div style="border:solid 1px blue;height:20px;margin-top:48px"></div>
</div>
```

The left node is using % padding, the right node is using fixed pixel padding. They should be identical but the % padding is completely off.

Any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: All those in-inline styles are a pain. use classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you do :)

vertical margin or padding takes parent's width as reference **when % is used** : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties & http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-top

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea!

Answer (score 1):

`margin-top: 20%` specifies a top margin which is 20 percent of the width of the containing element. What I see from your code that the width of the containing element is 600px. so the top margin comes to `120px`.Whereas in the case of right one it is only `48 px`. That is why they are not identical.

Comment: You're blowing my mind right now. Why would margin-top be affected by the WIDTH of the parent?? Insanity!